# Application crashes on creating object of ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

In my application when i try to create an object an object of a viewController class which I need to show as the landingScreen from appDelegate, my app crashes.

```
self.viewController = [[DiscoverViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DiscoverViewController" bundle:nil];
```

It goes to the `initWithNibName` method of the `DiscoverViewController` class, but crashes at `[super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]`.

The stack trace screenshot I have attached. I have enabeled the ExceptionalBreakpoint and enabled NSZombie but still hard luck.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Addition** :

```
    self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController]autorelease];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
```

Xcode 4.6
Device iOS - 7.1

[image]

Comment: Show your appdelegateDidFinish code..

Comment: @TamilKing - Made the edit

Comment: Is there xib File in your project name with DiscoverViewController.xib..?

Comment: @ParvendraSingh - YES

Comment: wait i will give you code for it ....

Comment: @NiKKi Just Copy and past my code it will run for you if you have DiscoverViewController.xib file in your project... Thanks

Comment: make sure in your nib file main view is connected to the File's owner.

Answer (score 0):

Write it in your AppDelegate.h.......

```
     #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
     @class DiscoverViewController;

 @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

 @property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
 @property (nonatomic,retain)  UINavigationController *nav;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) DiscoverViewController *viewController;

 @end
```

And write it in AppDelegate.m....

```
  #import "AppDelegate.h"
  #import "DiscoverViewController.h"

  @implementation AppDelegate

  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
   {
     self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];    
     self.viewController = [[DiscoverViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DiscoverViewController" bundle:nil];

     UINavigationController *nav =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

     self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
  }



@end
```

Comment: I have done quite the same coding. My app crashes at the time of `alloc`.

Comment: No. It is working for iOS6 simulator. I guess its iOS7.1 issue.

Comment: got that. It was the issue for extracting the UITextField from the SearchBar in iOS7. The hierarchy is not the same for UISearchBar as it as in iOS6. So it was crashing. But it was not giving and=y reason.